# ngPluralize and Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I would like to know how to use the [ngPluralize](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) directive along with the tooltip module from [Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) (the Angular UI fork)? The goal is to have a pluralized tooltip text...

Thanks by advance.
Valentin

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has answered this question yet, and I assume you have likely found an answer by now anyway, I figured I might as well chime in. The solution is fairly straightforward using the "Dynamic Popover" approach by defining the text in the controller.

Controller:

```
$scope.pluralizedTooltip = function(item) {
    if (item.someArray.length === 0) {
        return 'None exist';
    } else if (item.someArray.length === 1) {
        return '1 Exists';
    } else {
        return item.someArray.length + ' Exist';
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div popover-placement="top" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover="{{pluralizedTooltip(item)}}">
            Popover Trigger Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for sure, although using the ng-pluralize directive would be awesome.